# Bluetooth reconnect in background

Tags: raspbmc, bluetooth

I've managed to get bluetooth to work to connect my bluetooth keyboard on Raspbmc.  Using `/usr/bin/bluez-test-input connect 20:42:A1:00:96:34` in /etc/rc.local I can even get it connected for when I boot up the computer - so long as the keyboard is in connect mode.  The problem is that if the keyboard loses the connection, I can't seem to get it reconnected with the GUI session.

I built a small cron job that checks the output of `hcitool con` and reconnects when the connection dies, and it seems to work (as long as the keyboard is in connect mode).  It connections according to `hcitool con` and the keyboard indicates a connection, but it doesn't appear 'active' for the raspbmc gui session.
How can I get it to reconnect as such?

Comment: Hmm don't know but update your bluez to the latest version (apt-get update && apt-get upgrade). I know from playing around with bluetooth the auto reconnect not always works. I've found a link that may help, note that bluez updated and most of the information is not usable but give it a try: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth_mouse_configuration

Comment: This question should probably be closed because it has received no attention (outside of upvotes and a single comment) and was last modified over two years ago (September 8, 2012). This would indicate that either OP resolved the issue and hasn't self-answered the question or has simply moved on, which would be suggested also by the fact that OP hasn't been active on the site for over two years as well.

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness Keep in mind simply because a question is old and unanswered *isn't a reason in itself to close a question.*  However, this one is a bit convoluted/unclear/non-reproducible and off-topic, as it's really a general linux question.

Comment: I got totally the same problem with keyboard on `current` Raspbian and `current` bluez. It won't reconnect after disconnection. You have to restart whole thing.